# will javax validation annotations work on object fields which is in list

Tags: java, validation

I am using `javax.validation.constraints` annotaions for validation mobile number field in an object.
This object is inside list.

This annotations are not working, whats problem?

Comment: Where are you applying @NotNull constraints ? Over samplePhoneInfo or over phoneId in SamplePhoneRequest ?

Comment: @pattern(regex =somepattern) on phoneNumber

Comment: got it, missed @valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

missed @valid annotation

> Validation It is common to validate a model after binding user input
>   to it. Spring 3 provides support for declarative validation with
>   JSR-303. This support is enabled automatically if a JSR-303 provider,
>   such as Hibernate Validator, is present on your classpath. When
>   enabled, you can trigger validation simply by annotating a Controller
>   method parameter with the @Valid annotation: After binding incoming
>   POST parameters, the AppointmentForm will be validated; in this case,
>   to verify the date field value is not null and occurs in the future.

Answer (score 1):

When we declare an object inside an object. Validation with **javax.validation** does not work directly for the nested object.

To validate the nested referenced object having its own fields, we need to mark or annotate this nested referenced object with **@Valid** annotation in the parent object.

Then javax.validation will validate the nested object for constraints with the help of javax.validation implementation provider, for example, hibernate validator.

**@Valid** also works for **collection-typed** fields. **In the case of collection-typed fields, each collection element will be validated**.

**Following collection, types are supported with @Valid**.

- **arrays**
- **any collection implements java.lang.Iterable (especially Collection, List and Set)**
- **object implements java.util.Map**

For your use case, mark or annotate the **samplePhoneInfo** array list with @Valid annotation in the parent object and also mark or annotate **phoneNumber** with required annotation or regex pattern.

You can also check the same on the following URLs. Its a reference to official hibernate validator documentation.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#d0e410